# Random redirect evenly php

Tags: php, http, redirect, random

I have a simple php code that redirect to random uri from array.
However, after a while i've noticed its not evenly load balanced.
Can someone suggest tweaking so it will be evenly redirecting between the links ?

```
<?php 
$urls = array('https://a.com', 
               'http://b.com', 
               'http://c.com', 
               'http://d.com',
               'https://e.com',
               'https://f.com'
               ); 
shuffle($urls);
header('Location: ' . $urls[0]);
exit();
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: "However, after a while i've noticed its not evenly load balanced." https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Population_distribution.svg/2000px-Population_distribution.svg.png shows a random distribution, but it's not the *evenly distributed* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evenly and randomly are contradictory. But you can use a stack instead of an array to limit the randomness. Drawback is that you then need storage between script calls. For example :

```
<?php
$urls=readStack();
if(empty($urls)) {
         $urls = shuffle(array('https://a.com', 
                'http://b.com', 
                'http://c.com', 
                'http://d.com',
                'https://e.com',
                'https://f.com'
               )); 
$url=array_pop($urls);
storeStack($urls);
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Where storeStack() and readStack() functions are intended to store and retrieve your stack status from persistent storage. This could be done via file system storage, database access, or a memcache mechanism,... whatever is at your disposal and fast enough for your app. Here is a basic example with file system and serialize :

```
<?php
define( 'STOREFILENAME', '/tmp/urlstack');

function storeStack($value){
     file_put_contents(STOREFILENAME, serialize( $value ));
}

function readStack($varname){
     return unserialize(file_get_contents(STOREFILENAME));
}
```

Comment: "Evenly and randomly are contradictory." Not quite! An unbiased random number results in a uniform distribution over the aggregate. The problem is that `shuffle()` is not an unbiased random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**: `shuffle()` internally uses the same random number generator as `rand()`, which is biased, predictable, and has a small set of possible sequences (about 2^32, if I'm not mistaken).

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. [Persist some information across requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330188/2224584) to guarantee the distribution is even (which is what Guillaume's answer did).
2. Use an unbiased random number generator, such as [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int) (PHP 7, though a [(currently **experimental**) polyfill for 5.x](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) is in the works), which will in the aggregate produce an even distribution of outcomes.

For small sample sizes, solution #1 is probably the one you want. Over millions of requests, both should solve the problem.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could combine the two.

```
/**
 * An implementation of shuffle() that uses a CSPRNG to select indices
 * 
 * @param reference $array (pass a reference to an array)
 */
function unbiased_shuffle(&$array)
{
    $size = count($array);
    for ($i = $size - 1; $i > 0; --$i) {
        $r = random_int(0, $i);
        if ($r !== $i) {
            $temp = $array[$r];
            $array[$r] = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $temp;
        }
    }
    // Reset indices:
    $array = array_values($array);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your `header` line to choose a random index as well:

```
header('Location: ' . $urls[rand(0,count($urls) - 1)]);
```

Comment: That's just re-shuffling it, basically. If OP doesn't like the `shuffle()` results they won't like the `rand()` results either.

Comment: Also, `$urls[rand(0, count($array))]` suffers from an off-by-one error that will cause `E_NOTICE` errors.

Comment: I'm ok with using rand, but I hoped that on big numbers it will be evenly distributed. its not happening.    Actually maybe shuffling  twice might help.

Comment: Shuffling twice will not change probability distribution at all, but just slow you code down.